# How make this background blue properly?

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

Good morning,
I need to reproduce this shape but I don't know how to reproduce the blue background properly.
do you have any idea? the absolute position doesn't suit me because it's a responsive image.
For the image, I used the rotate property :

```css
  .content {
  display: flex;
  .image {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    img {
      transform: rotate(85deg);
    }
    @include media-screen-lg {
      padding-left: 24px;
      padding-right: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="text"></div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src={{content.field_image}}>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add some of the code you've tried? That would be helpful to get an answer on your post.

Comment: Yes, i added some codes :) :). thank you in advance

Comment: If you add `.image { background: blue; }` that should work, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a single child/container, you may use `width`, `background` and `rotate`, for example:

```css
.image {
  background: blue;
  width: max-content;/*shrinks to image's width */
  margin: 3em;
}

img {
  rotate: 5deg
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/520x550">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a psuedo elements, like this:

```
.image::before {
  background-color: blue;
  content: '';
  display: flex;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```